# How to avoid page refreshing after button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, web, devexpress

I've this problem for 3 days and I couldn't find the real answer.
I want that if I click a button the code will run and not to refresh all the page. For example:

ASPX code

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click"></dx:ASPxButton>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton2" runat="server" Text="Delete"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

CS code

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //new button
{
    ASPxButton2.Enabled = false;
}
```

That's basicly what I want to do. Click the new button and make the delete button enabled false without refreshing all the page.

What I tried:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click" onclientClick=" return false;"></dx:ASPxButton>
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="Button1_Click" onclientClick=" return false;"></asp:button>
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:button>
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="New" OnClientClick="DisableButton(); return false; "></asp:button>

function DisableButton() {
  document.getElementById("<%= ASPxButton2.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

Tried UpdatePanel too but I use MasterPage and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: your buttons runat is set as server.. It will run only in server(Am not sure) and you dont need to call CS code to disable and enable button, javascript is enough

Comment: You can use html buttons instead server control.and if you want to cal  cs code.Then go though ajax.

Comment: Could you give me an example Vivek Munshi

Comment: @Guest You can go through the below link:     http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: You mentioned UpdatePanel - which is how you'd do it. Maybe you need to clarify why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Use [`event.preventDefault()` Javascript Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Here is an example.

```js
function DisableButton(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.it">This goes to google!</a>
<a OnClick="DisableButton(event)" href="http://www.google.it">And this one don't!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to just disable button. I'll write another CS code too.

Answer (score 1):

Put AutoPostBack="false"  on your ASPxButton1. By default it's true.

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Text="New" OnClick="ASPxButton1_Click">
</dx:ASPxButton>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton2" runat="server" Text="Delete"></dx:ASPxButton>
```